# Use imwrite to write true color of the output of imagesc

Tags: image, matlab

Is it possible to write the image into rgb from the output of `imagesc` as the naked eyes can see? For example:

```
image=imagesc(rand(100,100)); %This is technically incorrect, but to show you what I meant
imwrite(image,'filename.bmp');
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an alternative to Cris Luengo's method which doesn't rely on the actual plot produced by `imagesc`.

```
% load a test image
I = rgb2gray(imread('peppers.png'));

% recreate image
cmap = colormap();          % grab current colormap
ncolors = size(cmap,1);
% do what imagesc does
Iind = double(I) - double(min(I(:)));
Iind = Iind / max(Iind(:));
% quantize image
Iind = round(Iind * ncolors + 0.5);
Iind(Iind > ncolors) = ncolors;
Iind(Iind < 1) = 1;
% convert to RGB from indexed image using cmap as palette
Irgb = ind2rgb(Iind,cmap);

imwrite(Irgb, 'filename.bmp');
```

Comparison of `imagesc` and *filename.bmp*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `print` function. It will write the contents of the figure window to an image file if you give it the right "device":

```
print -r0 -dbmp filename.bmp
```

Some tweaking of the figure window size and the position of the axes will make it so that the image is shown with one image pixel on one screen pixel, and without space around the axes:

```
set(gca,'units','normalized','position',[0,0,1,1]);
set(gcf,'units','pixels','position',[10,10,100,100])
```

(with the two 100 values the width and height of your image.)